# JButton not showing the Text in it

Tags: java, user-interface

This is my code I am Having Problem with the text in Jbutton, I'm new to Gui.

```
 class frame{
 JButton b1;
  frame(){
    b1=new JButton("+");
    b1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11));
    b1.setBounds(10, 60, 39, 23);
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    panel.add(b1);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setSize(246,281);
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("My Calculator");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(266,303);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
   }
```

Here is the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKGuc.png)

Comment: Your JButton is too small to display the text.  Remove all setSize, setBounds, and setLayout(null) method calls and use a [Swing layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to layout the Swing components.

Answer (score 0):

Your Button is too small. Increase the size, it works :)

```
...
b1.setBounds(10, 60, 200, 75);
...
```